# how can i make multiple of my enemy in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I cant figure out how to add multiple of my enemies, i got one enemy but i dont know how to duplicate it. I am kinda new to pygame so any help would be great!

skip past this next part it has nothing important

it told me to add more info so im adding that here with telling you it wanted more info for me to post this

here is my code:

```
import pygame, math

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 750
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500
SCREEN_COLOR = (160, 160, 160)

START_BUTTON_SIZE = .5
START_BUTTON_X = 280
START_BUTTON_Y = 320

EXIT_BUTTON_SIZE = .1
EXIT_BUTTON_X = 695
EXIT_BUTTON_Y = 5

player_x = 450
player_y = 250
player_width = 35
player_height = 40
player_vel = 4
player_color = (1, 40, 100)

Enemy_width = 30
Enemy_height = 30
Enemy_x = 100
Enemy_y = 100
Enemy_Vel = 1.5

FPS = 1000

Mouse_Pos = 0

Start = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

Start_Menu = pygame.image.load('Start_Menu.bmp').convert_alpha()
Start_Menu = pygame.transform.scale(Start_Menu, (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

Background = pygame.image.load('Background.bmp').convert_alpha()
Background = pygame.transform.scale(Background, (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT+10))

pygame.display.set_caption('Outlaw')

Enemy = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load("Start_Enemy.bmp").convert_alpha(), (Enemy_width, Enemy_height))

player = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load("Player.bmp").convert_alpha(), (player_width, player_height))

start_image = pygame.image.load('Start_btn.bmp').convert_alpha()
exit_image = pygame.image.load('Exit_btn.bmp').convert_alpha()

correction_angle = 90
class Button():
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.clicked = False
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

class Button():
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.clicked = False
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        
    def draw(self):
        action = False
        
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True
                
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                self.clicked = False
                
        
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        
        return action
    
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
start_button = Button(START_BUTTON_X, START_BUTTON_Y, start_image, START_BUTTON_SIZE)
exit_button = Button(EXIT_BUTTON_X, EXIT_BUTTON_Y, exit_image, EXIT_BUTTON_SIZE)

run = True
while run:
    
    clock.tick(FPS)
    
    
    
    
    if Start == False:
        screen.fill((SCREEN_COLOR))
    
        screen.blit(Start_Menu,(0, 0))
    
    if start_button.draw() == True and Start == False:
        print('START')
        Start = True
        player_x = 225
        player_y = 400
        
        #where you draw stuff
    if Start == True:
        screen.fill((SCREEN_COLOR))
        screen.blit(Background,(0, 0))
        
        player_pos  = player_x, player_y
        player_rect = player.get_rect(center = player_pos)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        dx, dy = mx - player_rect.centerx, my - player_rect.centery
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx)) - correction_angle

        rot_image      = pygame.transform.rotate(player, angle)
        rot_image_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = player_rect.center)
        
        screen.blit(rot_image, rot_image_rect.topleft)
        pygame.display.flip()

        
        Enemy_pos  = Enemy_x, Enemy_y
        Enemy_rect = Enemy.get_rect(center = Enemy_pos)

        dx, dy = player_x - Enemy_rect.centerx, player_y - Enemy_rect.centery
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx)) - correction_angle

        rot_image      = pygame.transform.rotate(Enemy, angle)
        rot_image_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = Enemy_rect.center)
    
        screen.blit(rot_image, rot_image_rect.topleft)
        pygame.display.flip()
            

    
    
    if Enemy_x < player_x:
        Enemy_x = Enemy_x + Enemy_Vel
    if Enemy_x > player_x:
        Enemy_x = Enemy_x - Enemy_Vel
    if Enemy_y < player_y:
        Enemy_y = Enemy_y + Enemy_Vel
    if Enemy_y > player_y:
        Enemy_y = Enemy_y - Enemy_Vel
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
      
    # if left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and player_x>0:
          
        # decrement in x co-ordinate
        player_x -= player_vel
          
    # if left arrow key is pressed
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and player_x<SCREEN_WIDTH:
          
        # increment in x co-ordinate
        player_x += player_vel
         
    # if left arrow key is pressed   
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and player_y>0:        
        # decrement in y co-ordinate
        player_y -= player_vel
          
    # if left arrow key is pressed   
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and player_y<SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        # increment in y co-ordinate
        player_y += player_vel
        
        
        
    if exit_button.draw() == True:
        print('EXIT')
        run = False
    
    
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
          

    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: with collisions?

Comment: or the enemies?

Comment: if its the enemies i got them working for the most part, i just cant make it so when the enemies touch the player it prints to the console dead

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Enemy_x` and `Enemy_y`, but create a list list for the enemy positions:

```py
enemy_positions = [[100, 100], [150, 100], [200, 100]]
```

Use `for`-loops to draw and move the enemies:

```py
while run:
    # [...] your code

    if Start == True:
        screen.fill((SCREEN_COLOR))
        screen.blit(Background,(0, 0))
        
        player_pos  = player_x, player_y
        player_rect = player.get_rect(center = player_pos)
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        dx, dy = mx - player_rect.centerx, my - player_rect.centery
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx)) - correction_angle
        rot_image      = pygame.transform.rotate(player, angle)
        rot_image_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = player_rect.center)
        screen.blit(rot_image, rot_image_rect.topleft)

        for enemy_pos in enemy_positions:
            enemy_rect = Enemy.get_rect(center = enemy_pos)
            dx, dy = player_x - enemy_rect.centerx, player_y - enemy_rect.centery
            angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx)) - correction_angle
            rot_image      = pygame.transform.rotate(Enemy, angle)
            rot_image_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = enemy_rect.center)
            screen.blit(rot_image, rot_image_rect.topleft)

        pygame.display.flip()


    for enemy_pos in enemy_positions:
        if enemy_pos[0] < player_x:
            enemy_pos[0] += Enemy_Vel
        if enemy_pos[0] > player_x:
            enemy_pos[0] -= Enemy_Vel
        if enemy_pos[1] < player_y:
            enemy_pos[1] += Enemy_Vel
        if enemy_pos[1] > player_y:
            enemy_pos[1] -= Enemy_Vel

    # [...] your code
```